# Oracle: How to query data so that the resultset contains Columns from Table A next to corresponding Columns from Table B?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a three tables as illustrated in the *screenshots below*:

I need to query the tables so that the `TAX`, `INSURANCE` and `BENEFIT` columns return next to their description:

Here is a query which shows the tax code column next to its description:

*Query:*

```
SELECT A.*, B.TAX, C.REQ_CODE_DESC AS TAX_DESC, B.INSURANCE, B.BENEFIT 

FROM BUSINESS A INNER JOIN LICENSE_REQ B ON A.LICENSE_ID = B.LICENSE_ID

LEFT JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC C ON B.TAX = C.REQ_CODE

LEFT JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC C ON B.INSURANCE = C.REQ_CODE;
```

**Tables:**

`BUSINESS` - `Primary Key LICENSE_ID`

[image]

`LICENSE_REQ` - `Foreign Key LICENSE_ID`

[image]

`LICENSE_REQ_DESC` - `Primary Key SEQ_NBR`

[image]

And here is the `resultset` screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you have to join multiple times : `Select a.*, b.tax, c1.req_code_desc, b.insurance, c2.req_code_desc, b.benefit, c3.req_code_desc from business a, license_req b, license_req_desc c1, license_req_desc c2, license_req_desc c3 where a.license_id = b.license_id and b.tax = c1.req_code and b.insurance = c2.req_code and b.benefit = c3.req_code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to join multiple times to the `LICENSE_REQ_DESC` table (one time for each description you want to show) and *alias them differently*.

Your final query could look like

```
SELECT bus.LICENSE_ID, 
  bus.BEGIN_DATE, 
  bus.END_DATE, 
  lr.TAX, 
  lrtax.REQ_DESC AS "TAX_DESC", 
  lr.INSURANCE, 
  lrins.REQ_DESC AS "INSURANCE_DESC", 
  lr.BENEFIT, 
  lrben.REQ_DESC AS "BENEFIT_DESC"
FROM BUSINESS bus
  JOIN LICENSE_REQ lr 
    ON (bus.LICENSE_ID = lr.LICENSE_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC lrtax 
    ON (lr.TAX = lrtax.REQ_CODE)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC lrins 
    ON (lr.INSURANCE = lrins.REQ_CODE)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC lrben 
    ON (lr.BENEFIT = lrben.REQ_CODE)
```

I put outer joins to the `LICENSE_REQ_DESC` table, to be sure you always return a row even if one of the `TAX`, `INSURANCE`, or `BENEFIT` field has no description. You can safely replace them with regular joins if this is not the case

Comment: I am getting syntax errors on all of the aliases: However, the concept you are using is the solution I need, I simply re-wrote the query using separate joins and aliases to remove ambiguity since all of the columns in the `LICENSE_REQ` table are referencing the same column in the `LICENSE_REQ_DESC` table.

Comment: Here is the working code:

`SELECT A.LICENSE_ID, 
       B.TAX, T.REQ_CODE_DESC, 
    B.INSURANCE, 
    I.REQ_CODE_DESC, 
    B.BENEFIT, 
    J.REQ_CODE_DESC

FROM BUSINESS A INNER JOIN LICENSE_REQ B ON A.LICENSE_ID = B.LICENSE_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC T ON B.TAX = T.REQ_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC I ON B.INSURANCE = I.REQ_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LICENSE_REQ_DESC J ON B.BENEFIT = J.REQ_CODE`

Comment: I forgot to put the column aliases between quotes, I updated my solution.